# XeLaTeX - special unicode characters

Tags: xetex, listings, unicode

I found that work with unicode characters is a lot easier using `xelatex` than `pdflatex`, therefore I'd like to use it. Most of the content is displayed correctly but I have a problem with some special unicode characters like `├` or `└` which aren't shown in the output.

My file looks like that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    These characters are working - +ľščťžýáí˝¨˘˛˙´°'

    These aren't - ├ └

    \begin{lstlisting}
        Listing: ├ └
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

So my question is: How to "enable support" for these characters? I want to use them in the `lstlisting` environment too.

Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: Did you test if other special characters are working? (you say you have problems with "some" characters). Can you provide a minimal working example like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299160/76157 ?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: This is a font issue. You need to use a font which has these characters.