# latexmk -xelatex produces texfile with empty page instead of unicode characters

Tags: xetex, latexmk

the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
ääßöüü
\end{document}
```

with the options: `latexmk -xelatex test.tex` results in a empty page.

what is wrong here?

logs:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 10 Nov 2013, version: 4.39.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex  -recorder  "test.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (./test.aux)
[1] (./test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets (test.pdf) are up-to-date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i missed `\usepackage{fontspec}`. I did understood XeTeX as it had built-in unicode support. Sorry.

Comment: Easy mistake to make.  I wonder if anyone has put together a guide as to what is the bare minimum MWE for the various compile methods.

Comment: @AFeldman ---yes; on the same topic I asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297463/latex-introduction-books-2-modern-documentation

Comment: Rmano I like your question, +1.

Comment: @AFeldman +1 for the idea.